# Reason for having separate tables for slots and days

Tags: fullcalendar

In the agenda day+week view there are two separate tables for days and slots.

The days table essentially has a blank left column, **x** number of full height columns for each of the days with the date at the top (in a `<thead>` tag), and finally a right gutter with the scrollbar.

The slots table has **y** rows for each time slot (obviously a dynamically calculated number of rows). They have two cells per row. One for the time (*12am*) and one full-width cell that is only used afaik to display alternating dotted/solid horizontal borders.

My question (to the devs hopefully) is why did you make this choice, when compared to one table that contains **x** columns and **y** rows? Do you have plans to consolidate it into one table?

The reason I'm asking is because I am forking the code now to make it so that individual days+time slots are addressable (i.e. set the bgcolor on 8-10am on nov 12th to be red ... or disallow events to be dropped there).

Comment: Mike, I want to do the same. Did you reach to any solution yet? Please share with me. Thanks

Comment: Yeah I did manage to figure it out a while ago. I think the file I was looking at was /src/agenda/AgendaView.js. Around line 288. You need to loop through several days rather than just once. No easy way about it other than editing the source JS directly